# Trying to get Pusher working with Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to broadcast using Laravel 5.1 to my front end JS using `Pusher`.

This is my front end code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>Pusher Test</title>
  <script src="https://js.pusher.com/2.2/pusher.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Enable pusher logging - don't include this in production
    Pusher.log = function(message) {
      if (window.console && window.console.log) {
        window.console.log(message);
      }
    };

    var pusher = new Pusher('2f89b1f8bcf257af0d8e', {
      encrypted: true
    });

    var channel = pusher.subscribe('test_channel');

    channel.bind('App\Events\NewChatMessage', function(message) {
      console.log(message);
    });
  </script>
</head>
```

This is my event:

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\Events\Event;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class NewChatMessage implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should be broadcast on.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return ['test_channel'];
    }
}
```

My keys are setup in the `broadcasting.php` config file.

And these are my routes:

```
/*
 * Pusher Test Routes
 */

Route::get('/fire', function() {
    event(new App\Events\NewChatMessage($message = ['name' => 'Martin']));

    return "Done";
});

Route::get('/test', function() {
    return view('test');
});
```

For some reason I don't get a response!

The frontend code is fine as I can receive data using the pusher debug console, so the issue appears to be on the Laravel site.

Any help would be appreciated :D

Comment: You didn't create public class variable as event's payload.

Answer (score 0):

Laracasts has an excellent video that covers exactly this topic. Watching that should get you going: https://laracasts.com/lessons/broadcasting-events-in-laravel-5-1

Comment: Thanks. I've done that already but having issues. I've updated the OP. :)

Comment: @lowerends, Seems you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45877837/how-can-i-make-realtime-notification-for-user-who-are-not-login