# How can I make realtime notification for user who are not login?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, notifications, real-time, broadcast

I use laravel 5.3

I created an online store website.

If user logs in and chooses a product then okay button, there will be realtime notification in icon cart.

My code looks like this :

If user selects product and okay button, it will run this function :

```
public function addNotificationCart()
{
    Notification::send(auth()->user(), new CartNotification($cart));
}
```

Then :

```
public function toBroadcast($notifiable) {
    return new BroadcastMessage([ 
        'id'        => $this->data->id,
        'time'      => $this->data->created_at,
        'group'     => 'cart'
    ]);
}
```

And my javascript code looks like this :

```
Echo.private('App.User.' + window.Laravel.authUser.id).notification((notification) => {
     // run this statement if exist notification        
})
```

If the code run, it works

I want to add a new feature on my website. So when the user is not logged in, the user can also add cart and there is will display notification cart

What matters to me is how I do it?

In this section :

```
Notification::send(auth()->user(), new CartNotification($cart));
```

And :

```
window.Laravel.authUser.id
```

It requires user data being logged and id

How do I fill it if the user is not logged on?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/broadcasting#concept-overview, you can create a public channel.

Comment: @Wreigh, There explains that it can use public channel. But there is no example of how to use it. i need a real example

Comment: @SuccessMan I didn't work on Public Channel yet. I'll get back to you as early as I can. :) Sorry for that.

Comment: Do you have any updates to this question as it is a really interesting question. Thanks in advance.